# Как очистить input type="file" компонент в Vue

Tags: vue.js

Как правильно очистить value инпута с типом file? На компонент BaseFileUpload я добавляю v-model="photo" но в консоли ошибка `"InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string."`

BaseFileUpload.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label v-if="label">{{ label }}</label>
        <input
            type="file"
            class="form-control-file"
            ref="fileupload"
            :value="value"
            @change="onChange($event.target.files)"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'BaseFileUpload',

    props: {
        label: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: '',
        },

        value: {
            type: File
        },
    },

    methods: {
        onChange(files) {
            this.$emit('change', files[0]);
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Form.vue

```
<BaseFileUpload v-model="photo" @change="onChangeFileUpload($event)" />
<button @click="clear()">clear</button>

data() {
        return {
            photo: null,
        };
    },

methods: {
  clear() {
    this.photo = null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приведенная ошибка

> не удалось установить свойство 'value' для 'HTMLInputElement': этот элемент ввода принимает имя файла, которое может быть программно установлено только в пустую строку

уже фактически содержит ответ.

Если мы не можем программно установить для `input type="file"` значение `value`, 
 значит директива `v-model` *для приведенной вами реализации* не подходит, потому что, директива `v-model` как мы знаем работает по принципу:

```
v-bind:value="searchText"
v-on:input="searchText = $event.target.value"
```

и для нашего случая, это значит, что при любом изменении `value` у `<input>` срабатывает обработчик, которые выполняет, указанную выше, логику, т.е. присваивает новое значение. Вот здесь то `Vue` и пробрасывает ошибку, что не может присвоить новое значение, потому что данный тип поля ввода - `type="file"`, как отмечено выше, не может быть программно изменен на отличное от пустой строки значение.

В интернете много дискуссий по этому поводу. Я приведу вам один из вариантов как пример решения вашей задачи. В код вставлены комментарии, думаю код не вызовет вопросов.

```js
const BaseFileUpload = Vue.component('BaseFileUpload', {
  props: {
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(e) {
      // здесь же можно подключить логику обработки файла (загрузку и прочее)
      // ...
      // или отдаем родителю файлы
      this.$emit('change', e.target.files);
      // также можно сразу очистить поле ввода
      // this.$refs.fileupload.value = null
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
        <label v-if="label">{{ label }}</label>
        <input
            type="file"
            class="form-control-file"
            ref="fileupload"
            multiple
            @change="onChange($event)"
        />
    </div>`
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    BaseFileUpload
  },
  data() {
    return {
      images: []
    };
  },

  methods: {
    onChangeFileUpload(data) {
      this.images = [];
      // Здесь получаем файлы
      // и можем подключить логику обработки
      // здесь изображения просто отрисовываются на экран
      [...data].forEach((element) => {
        this.createImage(element)
      });
    },
    clear() {
      // очищаем переменные
      this.images = [];
      // полю ввода файла присваиваем пустую строку, что и очищает его
      this.$refs.upload.$refs.fileupload.value = null;
    },
    createImage(file) {
      var image = new Image();
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e) => {
        this.images.push(e.target.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h3>Vue - загрузка файлов</h3>
  <base-file-upload ref="upload" label="Выберите изображение(я)" @change="onChangeFileUpload($event)">
  </base-file-upload>
  <div v-if="images.length > 0">
    <hr>
    <img v-for="image in images" :src="image" />
    <hr>
    <button @click="clear()">Очистить все</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Принцип такой:
убираем `v-model`, для очистки поля ввода используем `$refs`, в метод `onChangeFileUpload` подключаем логику обработки введенных файлов.